# Get folder path or file path in html using file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I am trying to get the full path of a file or a folder in html with a file selector. 
I tried to use input with type file but it does not give me a correct path.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Roy Baranes</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#getIt").click(function(){
                alert($("#label").val());
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="form">
            <input type="file" id="label">
            <button id="getIt">Import</button>
        </div>
        <header>
            <div>
                <p>Welcome, please type text to search</p>
            </div>
        </header>

        <form id="searchbox">
            <input id="search" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Type here">
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

when I want to choose a folder, I use following code:

```
<input type="file" id="label" webkitdirectory directory multiple>
```

but after I choose and type import the alert shows me following path 
c:\fakepath\ *the first file in the folder - whereas I was expecting this path: * \ *the file name that i choose - when i choose file*

Comment: You don’t get that path, for security reasons (`type="file"` is meant for uploading files to the server – the directory structure of the client is none of your business for that purpose).

Comment: use input.files[n].webkitRelativePath to get the path under the folder you selected.

Comment: there is no webkitRelativePath there is only 'webkitEntries = Array[10],webkitShadowroot = null,webkitdirectory = true,webkitdropzone = ""'